# Trimming user Library folder in OSX- what can be deleted?

Tags: macos

Trying to increase available space in way too small (250GB) internal iMac drive.
I noticed my Library folder is over 60GB!
cache folder alone inside Library over 18GB!

What can 'safely' be deleted from my Library folder?

Comment: If you don't know, leave it alone. Get something like CleanMyMac to help you... even then you need to be careful, it will clean 'too much' if you let it.

Comment: Do you mean `/Library` or `~/Library`?

Comment: the latter, the user's Library folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the user Library folder.
My user Library is about 13GB, 60GB looks big indeed.
I would not use CleanMyMac: very bad app.
What you don't know don't throw away.
You can use something like OmniDiskSweeper, that sorts files in size, and let's you delete. But without knowing exactly which file does what, it is stupid to throw away anything. It also does not work to throw out caches, because they are for intermittent storage and will come filled again quickly. Maybe the Cache folder has something corrupt in it. Throw away but realize that it will fill again. 
Look through the ApplicationsSupport folder to see if there old and unused or uninstalled applications.

Comment: Thanks. have you used latest Onyx?

Comment: eco_bach:
Onyx has nothing to do with "cleaning" of the library.